# AngularJS: Is '$scope.ctrl = $scope' good or bad?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

In AngularJS world, there are battle between '$scope' and 'Controller As'.
(Or, '$scope.ctrl = this' instread of 'Controller As'

But, how about '$scope.ctrl = $scope' ? Is this good or bad idea ?
By this, I can refer controller as variable to avoid accidentally use wrong scope's variables, without changing '$scope' style code.
But, I couldn't find this as a practice.
Why ?

Comment: @dandavis Yes in JavaScript code. But not in angular expression. By '$scope.ctrl = $scope', I can use "ctrl.variable" instead of "variable" in angular expressions of HTML files. (We cannot directly use "$scope" in angular expressions)